# Is there a Javascript/HTML form basics webpage/post? Built an Excel sheet, want to put it on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I'm trying to create a basic calculator for a blog post. I'm familiar with Python and Java, but am not super familiar with HTML/CSS.

From my Googling, it seems I need to use Javascript + HTML (please correct me if I need to use another language combo).

Basically, I'm comparing two things to see what will save more money for someone and want to spit out either Option A or B. I created the simple calculator in Excel but am not sure how to do it for a webpage. I'd just embed the Excel sheet, but iframes are not crawlable via Google for SEO purposes.

Here is an image:

[image]

The formula in cell B5 is this: =if((B2*B3+B4*0.05>B4*0.02+100),"Option A","Option B")

It basically calculates your value of the brunches + 5% cashback for A and checks if it is better than $100 + 2% cashback for option B.

Comment: You can start [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that embed an exel sheet in html sould work. You sould create a table with HTML and access it with javascript to do the math and display the result.
You could use a JQuery syntax or maybe an little AngularJS-app to make it easier, but I don't think it's essential.
Here are some good links for learning : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp ; https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp ; https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp. Hope this will help.